# Java/OpenGL missing triangles when loading and rendering vertexes from obj model

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, vertex

I am trying to load vertexes from OBJ file and render them. But only some triangles are rendering.

How the model should look:
[Blender model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmBkV.png)

How its rendered:
[Rendered model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGKeq.png)

My code:

```
  GL2 gl = glad.getGL().getGL2();
  gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   
  gl.glRotatef(0.5f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
   
  gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
  gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP); // Start Drawing The Cube
  try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\untitled.obj")) {
    
    final IOBJParser parser = new OBJParser();
    final OBJModel model = parser.parse(in);

    
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getVertices().size(); i++) {
        
        
        System.out.println(model.getVertices().get(i).x + " " + model.getVertices().get(i).y + " " + model.getVertices().get(i).z);
        
        gl.glNormal3f(model.getNormals().get(i).x,model.getNormals().get(i).y, model.getNormals().get(i).z);
        gl.glVertex3f(model.getVertices().get(i).x,model.getVertices().get(i).y, model.getVertices().get(i).z);
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EventListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EventListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    
}
  
  gl.glEnd();
  gl.glFlush();
```

*(I know this is far from the most efficient method)*

I am using **JOGL** library for the rendering and **java-data-front** for loading the obj file and parsing it. The model is loaded correctly, but not rendered.

Comment: Show the output of System.out.println(model.getVertices().get(i).x + " " + model.getVertices().get(i).y + " " + model.getVertices().get(i).z);

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8Au4HYZM it prints out the vertexes to check if there isn't problem in loading and as I checked it's same as the file, so its loaded correctly

Comment: @Maratonec A [Wavefront (OBJ)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_OBJ) consist of vertices and face indices. You need to iterate over the indexes and render the vertices in the order of the indexes.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks! Can you please give me some small code snippet?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I'm not familiar with _java-data-front_. (However, I know the OBJ format well)

Comment: @Rabbid76 you can access the vertex indexes in java-data-front using model.getObjects().get(0).getMeshes().get(0).getFaces().get(0).getReferences().get(0).vertexIndex . So when I have this value, what should I do with it? (sorry i am newbie)

Comment: Iterate through the faces indices and use the index to access a vertex coordinate `model.getVertices().get(vertex_index)`. Be aware the array indices start at 0, but OBJ indcies start at 1. Hence you need to do `vertex_index-1` somwhere.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. But really thanks for the face indices. I didn't know that they exists. I will self answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Self answering)

I'd have too loop for every object, mesh, and face. And then get the references and indexes as @Rabbid76 said.

The code:

```
        GL2 gl = glad.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   
  gl.glRotatef(0.5f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
   
  gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
  gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP); // Start Drawing The Cube
  try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\untitled.obj")) {
    
    final IOBJParser parser = new OBJParser();
    final OBJModel model = parser.parse(in);

     for (OBJObject object : model.getObjects()) {
    for (OBJMesh mesh : object.getMeshes()) {
    for (OBJFace face : mesh.getFaces()) {
        for (OBJDataReference reference : face.getReferences()) {
    final OBJVertex vertex = model.getVertex(reference);
    gl.glVertex3f(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
     if (reference.hasNormalIndex()) {
    final OBJNormal normal = model.getNormal(reference);
    gl.glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
}
if (reference.hasTexCoordIndex()) {
    final OBJTexCoord texCoord = model.getTexCoord(reference);
    gl.glTexCoord3f(texCoord.u, texCoord.v, texCoord.w);
}
}
    }
    }
    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EventListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EventListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    
}
  
  gl.glEnd();
  gl.glFlush();
```

Comment: You should also not be using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` but rather `GL_TRIANGLES`, since OBJ files contain individual (disjointed) polygons.

And on that note (polygons), each face should be rendered as a triangle fan. But since beginning new shapes (especially if you are using newer OpenGL paradigms) is slow, you have to emulate that via triangles:

    ```java
    for (int i = 1; i < face.getReferences().size() - 1; i++) {
      drawFaceVertex(face, 0)
      drawFaceVertex(face, i)
      drawFaceVertex(face, i+1)
    }
    ```

Sadly, I see this question two years too late.